# Android Httppost

Tags: java, android, http-post

Hi i am using below code to send data to server

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myurl.com/app/page.php"); 
// Add your data   
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);   
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "dave"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("taxi no", "354"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pack", "0"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exchk", "1"));

try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can successfully send data to server,but the server return larger amount of data(100Kb-200KB) in text format.I want to convert that text response into json object.so i am assigning all the response into one string to convert json object.

But That Response string contain only less amount of data.

I checked the server it send 112kb file but that response String contain only less data.say around (50kb-75kb).

So can u please any one guide me to solve the problem

Comment: try to read content of the String and compare that content. don't compare the size of the String

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is an expandable List item. So I have no idea what the purpose of using "5" as an argument. Second thing is BasicNameValuePair contains names and values as arguments. It is a good practice to use single word for a name attribute. Remove

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Add following code sample

```
try {
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

String bufferedStrChunk = null;

while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
    }

return stringBuilder.toString();

} catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
    System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);
    cpe.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

This return the page content in a readable format. Then you can pass it to a JSON file by using JSONObject and JSONArray.